# Show the last element of most frequent item in js array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have function that defines most frequent item in array and returns it. It waorks as expected except I want to show last item if there are two or more items with the same frequency score. For expample, I have an array `['grape', 'lemon', 'apple', 'grape', 'lemon']`, function will return `'grape'` and my goal is to return `'lemon'` in this case. I tried to use if statement but didn't figured the right way. Here is js code:

```
let fruits = ['grape', 'lemon', 'apple', 'grape', 'lemon'];

(function(array) {
  let mf = 1;
  let m = 0;
  let item;
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    for (let j = i; j < array.length; j++) {
      if (array[i] == array[j])
        m++;
      if (mf < m) {
        mf = m;
        item = array[i];
      }
    }
    m = 0;
  }
  console.log(item);
  return item;
})(fruits);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "last"? Last, as in, the largest index in the original array?

Comment: <= will work instead of <

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution is loop the array from higher index to lower index

```js
let fruits = ['grape', 'lemon', 'apple', 'grape', 'lemon'];

(function(array) {
  let mf = 1;
  let m = 0;
  let item;
  for (let i = array.length -1; i >=0 ; i--) {
    for (let j = i; j  >= 0; j--) {
      if (array[i] == array[j])
        m++;
      if (mf < m) {
        mf = m;
        item = array[i];
      }
    }
    m = 0;
  }
  console.log(item);
  return item;
})(fruits);
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use `<=` instead of `<`

```js
let fruits = ['grape', 'lemon', 'apple', 'grape', 'lemon'];

(function(array) {
  let mf = 1;
  let m = 0;
  let item;
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    for (let j = i; j < array.length; j++) {
      if (array[i] == array[j])
        m++;
      if (mf <= m) {
        mf = m;
        item = array[i];
      }
    }
    m = 0;
  }
  console.log(item);
  return item;
})(fruits);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could take a single loop with an object for counting the items and an array for the last item of the greatest count.

```js
function lastTop(array) {
    var count = {},
        last = [],
        value;

    for (value of array) last[count[value] = (count[value] || 0) + 1] = value;
    return last.pop();
}

var array = ['grape', 'lemon', 'apple', 'grape', 'lemon'],
    last = lastTop(array);

console.log(last);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just reverse your loops, start at the end of the array, and you can set `m = 1` and `j = i - 1` so that `i` will never equal `j` to avoid unnecessary comparison and addition:

```js
let fruits = ['grape', 'lemon', 'apple', 'grape', 'lemon'];

(function(array) {
  let mf = 1;
  let m = 1;
  let item;
  for (let i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    for (let j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
      if (array[i] == array[j])
        m++;
      if (mf < m) {
        mf = m;
        item = array[i];
      }
    }
    m = 0;
  }
  console.log(item);
  return item;
})(fruits);
```